# mysql save date from different datetime locals

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm having hard time to decide on the right approach for data saving from different time zones:

I'm building an application that supposed to serve users from all over the world.

I have a table named `Events` which saves events the users inserted.

In this table there are `Start_Time` and `End_Time` columns of the event, which I some time need to run a select query according to does columns, and in relevant to user's current time.

I'm thinking about what the best approach for saving does times in the database. obviously I have some lack of knowledge in the time zones field.

For now i'm saving all the times as current UTC time stamp, and i'm not sure that its the right way to do so.

can anyone please provide some guidelines or documents about to right way to store it ?

Answer (score 0):

hey according to my understanding you have a application that send request to this database on behalf of user, and user has its own date and time zone.
I would recommend to change your request time zone on application level to UTC. bring your application and database to same page and then after processing you can convert it back to local time zone.
what application language your are using?

Comment: the application side is in Java, and there is a php web service that receive requests. the user on his behalf sends the event's time in UTC. from some reason its hard for to understand that querying this data using the current utc time will work well for each time